# How to export attributes or annotations to an HDF5 file?

Tags: export, hdf5-format

I'm trying to export attributes and annotations to an HDF5 file. But the documentation [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/HDF5.html) is horrible and there are no examples of this.

I spent some time playing, but I can't get it to work. Here is the simplest example that should have helped me to get started:

```
Export["test.h5", {{{1, 2}, {2, 3}}, {{10, 11}, {12, 13}}}, {"Datasets", {"m1", "m2"}}]
r = Import["test.h5", "Rules"]
Export["test1.h5", r, "Rules"]
```

but it fails with:

> ```
> Export::errelem: The Export element Dataset1 contains a malformed data structure and could not be exported to HDF5 format. >>
> Export::noopen: Cannot open C:\Users\ajasja\Documents\test1.h5. >>
> ```

So my question is: **How can one export attributes with datasets?** (preferably using built in *Mathematica* functionality)

**EDIT**
For reference here are some external MMA HDF5 packages that might provide the required functionality, but I have not yet managed to write any attributes:

- [HDF5WrappersForMathematica](http://www.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/contrib/mathematica/) Uses .NET libraries to implement all the HDF5 calls
- [H5DumpImport](https://github.com/m2orris/h5dumpImport) which works through ascii dump files
- [h5mma](http://sourceforge.net/p/h5mma) which is a C implementation (but has read-only functionality)

Comment: Just wondering, is this resolved in version 10?

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, this isn't possible yet with Mathematica straight from the oven, but there is a package created by Scot Martin [here](http://www.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/contrib/mathematica/).

As far as I can see, it implements a lot of the HDF5 functionality, including Compound Types.

For attribute creation take a look at the following functions : `H5Acreate, H5Awrite, H5Aclose` (the `A` comes from "Attribute")

BTW, I think that `Annotations` are deprecated in V5.

Comment: Yup, I've seen the package. There is also [this](https://github.com/m2orris/h5dumpImport) which goes through intermidiate dump files and another one (I have the link at home) with C extensions.

Comment: Yes, you're right about the annotations, they are now attributes of the root group.

Comment: Also, Python makes this kind of stuff real sweet http://www.h5py.org/docs/intro/quick.html :)

Comment: @Ajasja as with other formats, Mma does a better job importing than exporting. I haven't an official confirmation, but my experiments show that writing attributes is not available

Comment: Regarding the extra package I get: `System.IO.FileLoadException: Mixed mode assembly is built against \
version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 \
runtime without additional configuration information.` out of the box (using MMA9). So if you provide a short example of writing attributes the (admittedly nominal) bounty is yours :) Aaa, for mma9 you probably have to download the 4.0 net assemblies from http://hdf5.net/

Comment: @Ajasja Nahhh ... I was just trying to help, I already have my own job :D

Comment: Yes, I know how it is. I'll post an answer if I get something working.

Comment: @Ajasja Did you get this working?

Comment: @GustavoDelfino No, I did not. I Switched to Python for data analysis. My life has been much easier since:)

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by adding a set of `"Attributes"` after the datasets. You can add all sorts of attributes and annotations:

```
Export["test.h5",
  {{{1,2},{2,3}},{{10,11},{12,13}}},
  {"Datasets",{"m1","m2"}},
  {"Attributes"->{
    "m1"->{
      "ScalarValue"->{10.0},
      "ArrayValues"->{1.0,2.0,3.0},
      "Info"->{"\"This is a text string\""}},
    "m2"->{
      "ScalarValue"->{20.0},
      "ArrayValues"->{-1.0,-2.0,-3.0},
      "Info"->{"\"This is a text string\""}}}}]
```

You can confirm the Attributes were saved:

> ```
> In[] := Import["example.h5", "Attributes"]
> Out[] := {{ArrayValues->{1.,2.,3.},Info->{"This is a text string"},ScalarValue->{10.}},{ArrayValues->{-1.,-2.,-3.},Info->{"This is a text string"},ScalarValue->{20.}}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

In Mathematica **12** there are two ways to export Attributes:

Either as a subelement to a dataset:

```
In[1]:= Export["test.h5", "path/to/dataset" -> {
    "Data" -> {1, 2, 3, 4},
    "Attributes" -> {
      "DataDescription" -> "SomeIntegers",
      "DataLength" -> 4
      }
    }
  ];
Import["test.h5", {"Attributes", "path/to/dataset"}]

Out[2]= <|"DataDescription" -> "SomeIntegers", "DataLength" -> 4|>
```

or as a separate Export element:

```
In[3]:= Export["test.h5", {
   "Datasets" ->
    "path/to/dataset" -> {1, 2, 3, 4},
   "Attributes" ->
    "path/to/dataset" -> {
      "DataDescription" -> "SomeIntegers",
      "DataLength" -> 4
     }
   }, 
   "Rules"
];
Import["test.h5", {"Attributes", "path/to/dataset"}]

Out[4]= <|"DataDescription" -> "SomeIntegers", "DataLength" -> 4|>
```

In M12 it is possible to add new attributes to existing objects in the file if you use `OverwriteTarget -> "Append"`:

```
In[5]:= Export["test.h5",
  "path/to/dataset" -> {
    "NewAttribute" -> <|"x" -> 1, "y" -> "z"|>
   }, 
  "Attributes", 
  OverwriteTarget -> "Append"
];
Import["test.h5", {"Attributes", "path/to/dataset"}]

Out[6]= <|"DataDescription" -> "SomeIntegers", "DataLength" -> 4, 
 "NewAttribute" -> <|"x" -> 1, "y" -> "z"|>|>
```

It is even possible to change values of existing attributes, with `"AppendMode" -> "Overwrite"` option:

```
In[7]:= Export["test.h5",
  "path/to/dataset" -> {
    "DataDescription" -> "New description of the data."
   }, 
  "Attributes", 
  OverwriteTarget -> "Append", 
  "AppendMode" -> "Overwrite"
];
Import["test.h5", {"Attributes", "path/to/dataset"}]

Out[8]= <|"DataDescription" -> "New description of the data.", "DataLength" -> 4,
 "NewAttribute" -> <|"x" -> 1, "y" -> "z"|>|>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see:

https://github.com/scotmartin1234/HDF5Mathematica

The package has the functionality you need for writing at low level. The high level functions are designed more for reading. The package could be expanded as open source project to develop the writing part. It's straight forward to assemble the low level functions into a more Mathematica-friendly format (i.e., the higher level functions), but it would take a volunteer to do so. My efforts and work have been on developing the reading side of the equation into a Mathematica friendly format.

This is version 2.00 (August 2016) of the package that was originally provided as version 1.00 in July 2011.