# How to write both Attributes and DataFormat to an HDF5 file?

Tags: export, hdf5-format

I can't figure out the command to Export an HDF5 file from Mathematica that includes both an Attribute and a DataFormat. I can do one or the other, but not both.

Related questions:

[How to export attributes or annotations to an HDF5 file?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22789/how-to-export-attributes-or-annotations-to-an-hdf5-file)

[How can I export to HDF5 with a specific Datatype ("DataFormat")](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100433/how-can-i-export-to-hdf5-with-a-specific-datatype-dataformat)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after trying a few more things, the following works:

```
Export["test.h5", {"Datasets" -> {"/m1" -> {{1, 2}, {2, 3}}, "/m2" -> {{10, 
11}, {12, 13}}}, "DataFormat" -> {"UnsignedInteger16", "UnsignedInteger8"}, 
"Attributes" -> {"m1" -> {"m1Attribute" -> "testAttribute"}}}, "Rules"]
```

Then `Import["test.h5", "DataFormat"]` and `Import["test.h5", "Attributes"]` give `<|"/m1" -> "UnsignedInteger16", "/m2" -> "UnsignedInteger8"|>` and `<|"/" -> <||>, "/m1" -> <|"m1Attribute" -> {"testAttribute"}|>, "/m2" -> <||>|>`, respectively.

Comment: One possible issue here is that currently export of group attributes does not work correctly. It does not affect your example, though.